# redirect after a POST to mongodb not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redirect

I'm going crazy!

I'm writing a simple messageboard with `node/mongoDB` where the user can open threads and comment on them.
After a POST to `/newthread`, which inserts the data to the DB (which works), I have a redirect to the `_id` of the document, but the server crashes with "Cannot read postTitle of undefined".

If I then restart the server and navigate to the thread (which is then shown on the index-page, as it was correctly inserted), I can view the thread without a problem.

only after I insert it and redirect, there seems to be no document found. 
I really can't figure out why, can someone help?

```
//index.js
router.post('/newthread', function(req, res) {
    threads.save(req, res);
});

//threads.js

var db = require('./db');
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/project';
var coll = 'documents';
var Oid = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

   module.exports.loadAll = function(cb) {
       db(uri, {}, function(err, db) {
           db.collection(coll, function(err, collection) {
               collection.find(
               {
                   $query: {},
                   $orderby: { "bumpedAt": -1 }
               }
            ).toArray(function(err, items) {
                console.log("Found items: " + items.length);
                cb(null, items);
            })
       });
   })
};

module.exports.loadOne = function(id, cb) {
    db(uri, {}, function(err, db) {
    db.collection(coll, function(err, collection) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("searching for id: " + id);
            console.log("converted to Oid: " + new Oid(id));
            collection.findOne({
                _id: new Oid(id)
            }, {}, function(err, item) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error " + err);
                    cb(err);
                } else if (item) {
                    console.log("Found item!");
                    console.dir(item);
                    cb(null, item);
                } else {
                    console.log("Found NO items");
                    cb(err);

                }
            })

        }

    })
    })
};

module.exports.save = function(req, res) {
db(uri, {}, function(err, db) {
    db.collection(coll, function(err, collection) {

        var time = new Date();

        console.log("Saving...");
        collection.insert({
            "op"            : req.body.username ||"Anonymous",
            "postTitle"     : req.body.posttitle || "No Title",
            "postContent"   : req.body.postcontent,
            "createdAt"     : time,
            "bumpedAt"      : time,
            "comments"      : []
        }, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                res.send ("Error while saving your post.")
            } else {
                console.log("Saved!");
                console.dir(doc);
                var threadId = new Oid(doc._id).toString();
                res.location('/thread/' + threadId);
                console.log("reloacting to " + threadId);
                res.redirect('/thread/' + threadId);
                console.log("redirecting to " + threadId);
            }
        })
    })
})
};


//thread.js (route to /thread/:id)
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log("loading " + req.params.id);
    threads.loadOne(req.params.id, function(err, item) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render('showthread', {
            title: item.postTitle,
            posts: item
        })
    }

    })
});
```

console output for saving a thread is:

```
Saving...
Saved!
{result: { ok: 1, n: 1 },
    // ...
}
relocating to 557d2305be8e753b0e0cf70a
redirecting to 557d2305be8e753b0e0cf70a
POST /newthread 302 96.992 ms - 120
loading 557d2305be8e753b0e0cf70a
searching for id: 557d2305be8e753b0e0cf70a
converted to Oid: 557d2305be8e753b0e0cf70a
Found NO items
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postTitle' of undefined
    at [...]/thread.js:16:28
```

> (that's at "title: item.postTitle,")

am I accessing it wrong?

The `id` is read, and it is correct. on the index, links are generated exactly from the `_id`, so this is totally correct. If I click an index link, I can see the thread. The redirected (after POST) url even shows the correct link (with that same id), but I can't loadOne with that id just after posting... why??

Comment: Hey, I think there might be a problem in passing both (req,res) to the threads.save method. Instead of that, just pass the object that needs to be inserted, insert the object and return the control back to the original (/newthread) method before redirecting.